# Why is subprocess throwing OSError here?

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, mod-wsgi

I have written my own module, mainly handling a filefield for a django site. After messing around with some things related to mod_wsgi (solved by updating to 3.3), i got my code to run. Right after all the necessary imports, before defining any classes or functions, i test for the availability of sox, an audiocommandlinetool essential to some of my modules functions:

```
sox = 'path/to/sox'
test=subprocess.Popen([sox,'-h'], shell=False, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
error=test.communicate()[1]
if error:
    raise EnvironmentError((1,'Sox not installed properly'),)
```

This worked fine. Now i have updated ubuntu from 8.04 to 10.04 and the code aborts on the line of the call to subprocess.Popen, throwing the following error message:

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 1139, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error
```

I already looked for execution rights of sox, i have no other idea where to look for a solution of this. Can subprocess execution rights be limited? Any hints what could be going on here?

Comment: What happens if you run subprocess with option `shell=True` and execute the app as you normally would in the console, like for example, `test=subprocess.Popen("/path/to/sox -h", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)` same result?

Comment: Hmmm, this results in the line `raise EnvironmentError ((1,'Sox not installed properly'),)` being executed, and the EnvironmentError is being raised. This happens with the developmentserver and apache/mod_wsgi. Sox can be started from the commandline without any trouble, so i can't imagine that i lost a kernel flag, as samurailawngnome suggested. And it can't be user-privileges as well, i have started sox as normal user, su and www-data...

Comment: The `raise` statement should show what was captured in `error`. It may be a legitimate sox error message.

Comment: @Apalala: Good hint, that solved the problem. Was definitely a problem with the version of sox being installed. I can't tell exactly why it worked in the commandline and not in subprocess, but it works now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hint of Apala solved the problem. Make sure to try different versions of sox, if the same thing happens again. Even if sox is working on the commandline, it can cause trouble with subprocess.

Comment: I ran into this Q/A with a similar problem today.  The 'shell=True' worked for me.  It had to do with my LD_LIBRARY_PATH, and the executable trying to link a differnt .so than I expected.  I add the comment here in hopes that it helps someone else.

Answer (score 1):

Try actually executing sox, as the same user that your django wsgi process is running.

It's possible that the binary isn't executable by that user, or that when you upgraded from 8.04 to 10.04, you lost some kernel flag allowing certain binary types to be executed.

Comment: Logged in as www-data, as specified in the site configuration for the wsgi daemon. Executing sox from the commandline worked well. Is that what you suspected?

Answer (score 1):

If you're on Linux and get "OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error" -- check if the kernel and executable are for the same platform -- 32bit vs 64bit.  `uname -a` and `file <executable path>` will do the trick.  This was my solution (and this page is the first hit for that error).

Comment: Is it possible to a 32 bit process to exec() a 64 bits one?